# MATLAB - Evaluate a function at each point in meshgrid?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I wish to plot the heat map of a bivariate (independent) Gaussian. To plot it over a 2D square, I did

```
joint_pdf = @(m, s) normpdf(m, 1, 1)*normpdf(s, 1, 1);
[x, y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:10, 0:0.1:10);
prob_map = zeros(numel(x), numel(y));
for idx1 = 1:size(prob_map, 1)
    for idx2 = 1:size(prob_map, 2)
        prob_map(idx1, idx2) = joint_pdf(x(idx1), y(idx2));
    end
end
image(prob_map);
```

This is very very slow. Is there a way of avoiding the looping?

Comment: your function is definitely wrong, you are repeating every point 101 time...
In addition, your problem is symmetric (  joint_pdf(x,y)=joint_pdf(y,x)   )

Comment: why can't you just do normpdf(x).*normpdf(y) 
http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html

Comment: @alexandreiolov because later I also have self-defined function. So would be great if I have a generic solution.

Comment: hm, try me again - the question asks whether you can avoid the loop in the code-snippet above, normpdf(x).*normpdf(y), does that. Should the question then not be "how to vectorize the self-defined function?"

Comment: Curious, if the solution provided here work for you?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry Sir, I forgot to accept. Thanks for pinging!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can hack into `normpdf.m` and get all the elements of `prob_map` in a  [vectorized manner](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) and thus also avoid those many function calls, which must make it much more efficient. I like to call this hacked approach as using the "raw version" of [`normpdf`'](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html)s implementation. Here's the final code -

```
%// Define arrays for inputting into meshgrid
array1 = 0:0.1:10;
array2 = 0:0.1:10;
[x, y] = meshgrid(array1, array2);

%// Define parameteres for normpdf
mu = 1;
sigma = 1;

%// Use "raw version" of normpdf to calculate all prob_map elements in one go
dim1 = exp(-0.5 * ((x(:) - mu)./sigma).^2) ./ (sqrt(2*pi) .* sigma);
dim2 = exp(-0.5 * ((y(:) - mu)./sigma).^2) ./ (sqrt(2*pi) .* sigma);
prob_map = bsxfun(@times,dim1,dim2.');
```

If you are interested in further speeding it up, you can pre-calculate few more stuffs surrounding the `x(:)` and `y(:)` in `dim1` and `dim2` respectively!